# bash - change directory inside a script wont work

Tags: bash, cd

Try to find a solution for a problem but stucked with the following :

I have a path of a folder (I got full path and partial path). 
Im tying to cd to that folder, but it keep saying "No such file or directory". 
Thats the partial code :

```
for var in "$@" ; do
    if [[ -d $var ]] ; then
        if [ "$(ls -A $var)" ]; then
            cd $var
```

Would appericiate any help :)
Thanks

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x scriptname args...` so that it will show the commands as it's executing them, this may help find the problem.

Comment: How sure are you that the `cd` command is what's giving you `No such file or directory`? Like, if you precede that command by `echo Before >&2` and follow it by `echo After >&2`, do you get `Before` followed by `No such file or directory` followed by `After`?

Comment: Also -- are you sure that you want to `cd` inside the loop, without setting up any sort of subshell? If you were to run your script with the arguments `dir1 dir2 dir3`, it would end up inside `./dir1/dir2/dir3/`, rather than just inside `./dir3/`. Your current approach seems like it would only work if either that's actually what you want (each argument is relative to the previous), or if all of your arguments are absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem:

```
    if [ "$(ls -A $var)" ]; then
```

Why do you need this test at all?  Your previous check looks for the existence of the directory already.

Comment: I need to check if the folder is empty :\

Comment: Why?  If you go to an empty folder you're not going to find the file you're looking for, so you can just backtrack from that point, right?

Comment: Are there spaces in the directory names?  You might need `"$var"` in all of those places.