# Bash: cd to directory provided by program output

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, alias

I have a short shell program that returns a system path. What I want to do is CD to that path using a bash alias.

My ideal output is

```
~$ pwd
    /home/username
~$ mark home
~$ cd /
/$ pwd
    /
/$ place home
~$ pwd
    /home/username
```

I have the "mark" part working, but the "place" is not:

```
alias place="cd \"~/marker.sh go $@\";"
```

My idea is that I want to cd to the output of `~/marker.sh go $@`

The problem is that bash is interpreting this as one command, and gives the errors:

```
-bash: cd: ~/marker.sh go : No such file or directory
-bash: home: command not found
```

which I assume means that the shell is parsing the entire alias as a string.

I've tried various forms of quoting for the shell script part of the alias $(), ``, etc, but they either try to run the script on bash start, or don't execute at all and just remain a string.

I'm programming this mostly to learn bash commands, but I can't figure out this one part!

I'm running OSX 10.9 in iTerm 1.0.0.20130624, if that's important.

Edit: I understand that [cd-ing inside a script won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752776/bash-change-directory-inside-a-script-wont-work), which is why I'm trying to just return the correct path using my program and use the built-in alias system to do the actual changing of directories.

Comment: By the way, have you looked at the directory stack feature of `bash`, specifically the `popd` and `pushd` commands?

Comment: Like I said, I'm very new to bash scripting. I'll check those out now!

Comment: They're very similar to what you are trying to do, although you are implementing a hash table of directories, rather than a stack.

Comment: Yeah - a hash table is what I want. I'm also storing the hash table (actually using a python dictionary in a different script) that then stores the dict as a flat file on my hdd so I can jump around on my OS using custom names for commonly visited directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function, not an alias:

```
place () {
    cd $( ~/marker.sh go "$@" )
}
```

Aliases do not take arguments; they simply expand in-place, with the arguments occurring after whatever the alias expanded to.

(You should always prefer a function to an alias unless the function cannot be adapted to do what you want.)

Comment: Ah okay - but how do I get the function to modify the scope of the main shell - that is, actually change my working directory, instead of just cd-ing inside this function and then returning my to my current working directory? Where would I put this script?

Comment: This function will modify the working directory of the shell that calls it. It's up to you to make sure that `place` is called by your current shell, and not in a script that is not sourced.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you! I'm going to try this now.

Answer (score 2):

Use functions, not aliases or external bash script!

in your `.bashrc` or any file sourced by it, or any file that you will manually source, put this fully usable script!

```
declare -A _mark_dir_hash

mark() {
   [[ -z $1 ]] && { listmarks; return 0; }
   if [[ -n ${_mark_dir_hash[$1]} ]] && [[ $1 != ${_mark_dir_hash[$1]} ]]; then
       echo "Mark $1 was already set to ${_mark_dir_hash[$1]}... replaced with new mark"
   fi
   _mark_dir_hash[$1]=$(pwd)
}

place() {
   [[ -z $1 ]] && { echo >&2 "You must give a mark name to go to!"; return 1; }
   [[ -z ${_mark_dir_hash[$1]} ]] && { echo >&2 "Mark $1 unknown!"; return 1; }
   cd "${_mark_dir_hash[$1]}"
}

listmarks() {
   [[ -z ${!_mark_dir_hash[@]} ]] && { echo "No marks!"; return 0; }
   for i in "${!_mark_dir_hash[@]}"; do
      printf '%s --> %s\n' "$i" "${!_mark_dir_hash[@]}"
   done
}

removemark() {
   [[ -z $1 ]] && { echo >&2 "You must give a mark name to remove!"; return 1; }
   unset _mark_dir_hash[$1]
}

clearmarks() {
   _mark_dir_hash=()
}
```

Ha, I just realized you're on mac, so you might be stuck with an antique version of bash which doesn't support associative arrays. Too bad for you. Yet, this might be useful to other people using modern shells!

Comment: Very cool implementation! I'm just outsourcing the heavy lifting to a python program since I'm more familiar with that, and hooking into it using bash functions.

Comment: I think the only difference here is that your version doesn't save to disk (so that the marks are saved across sessions).

Comment: Still, +1 for writing all this :D

Comment: I use 4.2.45 version of Bash with GNU version of the main shell commands (all of coreutils, sed, awk, grep, ...) on Mac OS X. It's not a default configuration but it's easily possible ;)